# Regular expressions and logical AND operator

Tags: php, regex

Tried to insert AND operator in Regular Expression, but after some searching I realized that Regular Expression does not support AND operator. Can anyone help me in suggesting alternative AND operator. Problem is: I need to find words which in our vocabulary and highlight them, but words which inside tags must be untouched. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you give an example of the text you want to match/not match?

Comment: Please provide the regular expression you have so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (preg_match($vocab, $word) && !preg_match($tag, $word)) highlight($word);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have two choices:

1.

```
if(preg_match($pat1, $subject) > 0 && preg_match($pat2, $subject) > 0){ 
    /* do something */ 
}
```

2. use positive/negative lookahead to simulate AND:

Example: match any html tags except `span` and `div`: `</?(?!span\b)(?!div\b)[^>]+>`
by De Morgan's Law = `</?(?!(span|div)\b)[^>]+>`

I hope these can help you :)